# Create an custom SQL Azure Alert that can be initiated by anyone

Tags: azure, alerts, sql-azure-alerts

I am trying to create a custom Azure Alert that sends an email whenever "A SQL Database is created by anyone" in any resource group across my subscription.

Is this even possible?

When I put a * in the "Event Initiated by" box (see image), it wont let me save and throws an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I put a * in the "Event Initiated by" box (see image), it wont
>   let me save and throws an error.

You don't need to put a *

Just leave the field empty and it should take a value of "any" once you're done.

> I am trying to create a custom Azure Alert that sends an email
>   whenever "A SQL Database is created by anyone" in any resource group
>   across my subscription.

I see a difference between the wording here and the rule you're trying to configure as per the image in your question. I say this because in the image you seem to select "testserver/testdb" as target under a particular Resource group "SQL-Sandbox".

This configuration will not be equivalent to monitoring across your subscription.

If you want to monitor across your subscription, you can configure your target in 2 possible ways. I quickly tried this out as well in a free subscription and will show screenshots.

1. Target is simply the top level subscription and nothing else.
2. Target is All databases under the top level subscription.

### **Screenshots for target as per type 1**

[image]

[image]

### **Screenshot for target as per type 2**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. is it possible to create an alert "email me if any resource is created or deleted" at the subscription level. I couldnt find it.

Comment: you're welcome. I did try briefly but couldn't find a way either. You could open a new question with that scenario if it's something you're interested in.. may be someone else knows about it :)